# Twilio Send Message API Error 21603

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I'm using postman to see the response format of send message api in Twilio. The Api that I'm using is https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.
I have entered the basic authentication parameters (Account_Sid and AuthToken as username and password) the json request format is

```
{
"To":"My Number",
"From":"Twilio Number",
"Body":"Hello this msg is from postman"}
```

But I'm getting error 21603 which states "A 'From 'phone number is required". Can you please tell me where I'm wrong. The messages are sent when using Twilio console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "A From phone number is required" in JSON call to Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764125/getting-a-from-phone-number-is-required-in-json-call-to-twilio)

Comment: Not really @HassanImam that didn't helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your Postman but, maybe this is what you're missing...

*Click on the Body tab and make sure **form-data** is selected from the radio buttons.*

[image]

---

Also if you go to Twilio docs page (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) you can see the expected response if you click on the **OUTPUT** link (tab) that is located at the top right of the code sample.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex Baban,Thanks for the reply. I was able to get the json response but the problem is I'm not able to send the request as json. Is form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded the only way to send a request to Twilio Rest messaging api?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. As far as I know, you're correct, form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded is the only way to send a request to send a message with Postman.